# Javascript popup closing event with asynchronous call

Tags: javascript, popup

Complete Java script : https://jsfiddle.net/v4bwfopm/1/

In this current script

```
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    alert("s");
}
```

Popup is closing only after displaying alert ("s").

How to make to display the alert only after closing the popup .?

I added   alert("s"); after the close event , in that case alert displayed before popup .

Screen shot:
[image]

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
  alert("s");
}
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<h2>Modal Example</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use setTimeout, so your code can be span.onclick as follows

```
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    setTimeout(function(){
    alert("s");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`alert()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert) method blocks the browser to update the CSS, to avoid that provide a delay using [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) method.

```
// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
  setTimeout(function() {
    alert("s");
  })
}
```

From MDN docs:

> Dialog boxes are modal windows - they prevent the user from accessing the rest of the program's interface until the dialog box is closed. For this reason, you should not overuse any function that creates a dialog box (or modal window).

Answer (score 0):

just use `setTimeout(function(){alert("s");},0);`